# I am trying to move the x axis from bottom to top in matplotlib. But xaxis.set_ticks_position('top') does not seem to work as it should?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am plotting a log using matplotlib and would like my x axis to be position at the top of the plot rather than bottom.

I tried xaxis.set_ticks_position('top') but it did not work. However xaxis.set_label_position('top') worked for the label.

```py
from matplotlib import gridspec

# creating the figure
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))

# adding the title
fig.suptitle('Volume of Clay from different methods',fontsize=14)

# creating the axes
gs=gridspec.GridSpec(4,3)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(gs[:,0])
ax2=fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
ax3=fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1])
ax4=fig.add_subplot(gs[2,1])
ax5=fig.add_subplot(gs[3,1])
ax6=fig.add_subplot(gs[:,2],sharey=ax1)

# Plotting graph for GR,SP
ax1.invert_yaxis()
ax1.xaxis.set_label_position('top') 
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.set_ylabel('DEPTH')
ax1.set_xlabel('GR[api]',color='green')
ax1.tick_params('x',colors='green')

ax1.spines['top'].set_position(('outward',0))
ax1.plot(data.GR,data.index, color='green')

ax11=ax1.twiny()
ax11.plot(data.SP,data.index,color='blue')
ax11.set_xlabel("SP[mV]",color='blue')
ax11.spines['top'].set_position(('outward',40))

plt.show()
```

i am expecting the x axis for the GR curve in green to be on top but it remains in the bottom instead.

[image: Image:]

Comment: You probably need to use `ax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')` *after* you created the twin axes, else it would be overridden.

Comment: I noticed that once I added the ax11=ax1.twiny(), it overwrites the ax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top'). how can i change this?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found out what's going on thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

ax11.ax1.twiny() is overwriting ax1

i've fix the code as below.

```py
from matplotlib import gridspec

# creating the figure
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))

# adding the title
fig.suptitle('Volume of Clay from different methods',fontsize=14)

fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9,wspace=0.3, hspace=0.3)

# creating the axes
gs=gridspec.GridSpec(4,3)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(gs[:,0])
ax1.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
ax3=fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1])
ax4=fig.add_subplot(gs[2,1])
ax5=fig.add_subplot(gs[3,1])
ax6=fig.add_subplot(gs[:,2],sharey=ax1)

# Plotting graph for GR,SP
ax10=ax1.twiny()
ax10.invert_yaxis()
ax10.xaxis.set_label_position('top') 
ax10.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
ax10.tick_params('x',colors='green')
ax10.spines['top'].set_position(('outward',0))
ax10.grid(True)
ax10.set_ylabel('DEPTH')
ax10.set_xlabel('GR[api]',color='green')
ax10.plot(data.GR,data.index, color='green')

ax11=ax1.twiny()
ax11.plot(data.SP,data.index,color='blue')
ax11.set_xlabel("SP[mV]",color='blue')
ax11.spines['top'].set_position(('outward',40))
```

[image]

If there are any better way to write this please do comment.